# Preview of html form with on click email fwd and opens a html form

Tags: php, cakephp, phpmyadmin, cakephp-1.3, php-5.2

preview of form data of an html form at the same time send email and open a new form

control flow is like this

form1.html// included email1.php in action

form2.html// i included in email1.php

email2.php// i included success.html

please help in previewing the form1.html right after sudmiting it and then to form2.

Comment: can you put your code? it would be kinda easy to see what is the problem at hand

Comment: in first form [form action="1.php"] in 1.php mail(to,msg,sub) include('form.html'); now i want a code that gives preview befor sending email and opens the form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make another php with session or with mysql fetching the result through table. Example of the coding using session:

getresult.php

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname']; // Gets the form's input
    $fname = $_SESSION['fname']; 
    ?>
```

preview.php

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    $firstname = $_SESSION['fname']
    ?>


     <form action="" method="post"> <!-- Show the form -->
     <input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $firstname; ?>">
     </form>
```

On the email part you should what should right?

Comment: thanks for the rply...am gonna try it now